# Distance between two points without using the square root

Tags: c, distance, points, square-root

Is it possible to calculate the distance between two points without having to use the math.h library? I know that, using the math.h library, it would have to be something among these lines (Euclidean distance formula):

```
int Distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)

    {
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;
    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    }
```

However, is there a way of doing this exact same thing but without using the square root (which needs the math.h library)?

**EDIT:** Whenever I try the following code, it gives me Floating Point Exception (Core Dumped):

```
float sqrt(int x) {
        int i;
        float s;
        s=((x/2)+x/(x/2)) / 2; /*first guess*/
        for(i=1;i<=4;i++) { /*average of guesses*/
            s=(s+x/s)/2;
        }
        return s;
    }

float Distance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    float dx = x2 - x1;
    float dy = y2 - y1;
    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}

int main() {
  printf("%f", Distance(1, 2, 2, 1));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure there is, but you would basically be duplicating code from the math library.

Comment: Note that `math.h` is a header, not a library, and that the math functions are part of the standard C library. (Many many years ago, when systems were much smaller and memory was a real thing that you could really use up, the math functions were broken out into a separate library that could be left unlinked if you didn't need it.)

Comment: Since you did not specifically say what is your goal, I want to just add that for comparisons (a common usecase), `(dx*dx + dy*dy)` will do since "the square root does not change the order" ([Squared Euclidean distance on English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Squared_Euclidean_distance)). Also, if any distance will do, I suggest you take a look at other norms as well (since technically you never said "It has to be Euclidean" or "Have properties x and y as in Euclidean". Off my mind, Supremum & Manhattan (p1) norms are 2 examples without square root in definition.

Answer (score 5):

```
int int_sqrt(int x){
    int s, t;

    s = 1;  t = x;
    while (s < t) {
        s <<= 1;
        t >>= 1;
    }//decide the value of the first tentative

    do {
        t = s;
        s = (x / s + s) >> 1;//x1=(N / x0 + x0)/2 : recurrence formula
    } while (s < t);

    return t;
}
```

Comment: where do N, x1 and x0 come from ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Try it out.

```
float sqrt(int x) {
    int i;
    float s;
    s=((x/2)+x/(x/2)) / 2; /*first guess*/
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++) { /*average of guesses*/
        s=(s+x/s)/2;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the exact answer! However, whenever I try the following code, it gives me Floating Exception (Core Dumped): (post edit)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. Does your debugger give any hints?

Comment: Calling the function with `x=0` or `x=1` will lead to a division by 0 in `s=((x/2)+x/(x/2))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Babylonian methods to calculate square root.  This method uses successive approximations to calculate square root.

Here is how it works

Let's say you want to calculate sqrt of 1234.

Let S =  1234,

D is number of digits in S which is  = 4.

If D is even we will represent it as D = 2n+2
else if D is odd  D =  2n + 1;

Here D is even so  4 =  2*1+2, so n=1.

Approx squere root of Sapprox  = D * 10^n  = 4 * 10^1 = 40

Let's call this X0  = Sapprox = 40.

X0 is 0th approximation.

Since S has 4 digits you will have to calculate 3 more approximations and X3 will be 
correct square root of S.

so 
X1 = 0.5(X0 + S/X0);
 X1 =  0.5(40 + 1234/40) = 35.425

X2 = 0.5(X1 + S/X1);
 X2 = 0.5(35.42 + 1234/35.42) = 35.129

X3 = 0.5(X2 + S/X2);
 X3 = 0.5(35.129 + 1234/35.129) = 35.128

sqrt(1234) = 35.128

Answer (score 0):

distance calculations on a grid generally use a formula that involves the calculation of square roots. Effectively, the only way to calculate square roots without calling the sqrt() function that is part of the standard C library, is to reimplement it, poorly.

Why do you want to do that? (Or are you asking, "how can I do this without calculating square roots"? That's not a programming problem anymore.)

Answer (score 0):

Look Ma! No `<math.h>` (but still needs to link with *libm*)

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double distance(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1) {
    return cabs((x0 + I*y0) - (x1 + I*y1));
}

int main(void) {
    printf("==> %7.2f\n", distance(1, 2, 2, 1));
    printf("==> %7.2f\n", distance(1, 0, 4, 0));
    printf("==> %7.2f\n", distance(1, 1, 4, 4));
}
```

Comment: Of course, `cabs()` will be implemented using some variation of `sqrt()`...